# xml schema definition issue

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

what is the xml schema for the following input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<string>&lt;!--This file generated by the XMLPull tool on 06/29/2012 03:24:18 AM--&gt;
&lt;!--Datasource: Ticket--&gt;
&lt;DATASET&gt;&lt;DATAROW&gt;&lt;TicketDesc&gt;Test Data. Do not Close.&lt;/TicketDesc&gt;&lt;/DATAROW&gt;&lt;/DATASET&gt;</string>
```

to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><!--This file generated by the XMLPull tool on 6/29/2012--><!--Datasource: Ticket--><DATASET><DATAROW TicketDesc="Test Data. Do not Close."/></DATASET>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "to this"? You've given two files, what is their relationship? "To this" implies the second one is the output of some kind of processing, but what processing?

Comment: the first is the output from a web service which doesn't quite know how to get the data to look like the part below. What is inside both code snips is the same, except the first has a strange formatting

Comment: I think you need to explain more clearly what you are trying to do and what problem you are encountering. Downvoting your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any given input document, there's an infinite number of schemas to which it conforms. Your first input document contains a single `<string>` element that contains some (rather complex) text. At two opposite ends of the spectrum, one possible schema is a schema that allows a `<string>` element with any content whatsoever, and another is a schema that allows a `<string>` element that is required to contain exactly the text you have shown. You've given no clues as to where on this spectrum you want your schema to be - that is, how constraining you want it to be.

Remember that a schema describes a class of documents. We can't induce that class from a single instance of the class.